# Pandas Test Failure

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

After installing Python 3.6.2 and Pandas on Windows 10 64-bit I ran the test described [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#running-the-test-suite). The failures seem to be largely linked to two issues.

---

The first 3 errors have to do with indexing:

- TestMixedIntIndex.test_argsort & TestMixedIntIndex.test_numpy_argsort

`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

`AssertionError: "'>' not supported" does not match "'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'"`

- TestMixedIntIndex.test_numpy_argsort

`Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'IndexError'>`

---

The remaining 3 errors appear to be date and time issues:

- TestDST.test_fallback_plural

`def test_fallback_plural(self):
    # test moving from daylight savings to standard time import dateutil
    ...
def _test_offset(self, offset_name, offset_n, tstart, expected_utc_offset):
    ...
    AssertionError: assert -7.0 == -8`

- TestTimeZoneSupportDateutil.test_ambiguous_flags

`AssertionError: assert Timestamp('2013-10-27 01:00:00+0100', tz='dateutil/GB-Eire', freq='H') == Timestamp('2013-10-27 02:00:00+0100', tz='dateutil/GB-Eire', req='H')
        + where Timestamp('2013-10-27 02:00:00+0100', tz='dateutil/GB-Eire', freq='H') = Timestamp('2013-10-27 01:00:00+0000', tz='dateutil/Europe/London', freq='H')`

- TestTimeZones.test_ambiguous_compat

`def test_ambiguous_compat(self):
        # validate that pytz and dateutil are compat for dst when the transition happens
        ...
        assert (result_pytz.to_pydatetime().tzname() == 
                result_dateutil.to_pydatetime().tzname())
        AssertionError: assert 'GMT' == 'BST'
             - GMT
             + BST`

---

Finally, I got the following warning summary:

`/Path/To/Tests/test_missing.py::test_array_equivalent_compat
/Path/To/nump/core/numeric.py:2604: FutureWarning: elementwise == comparison failed and returning scalar instead; this will raise an error or perform elementwise comparison in the future.
    return bool(asarray(a1 == a2).all())`

Edit 1:

Output of `pd.show_versions()`

`INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------`

`commit: None
python: 3.6.2.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Windows
OS-release: 10
machine: AMD64
processor: Intel64 Family 6 Model 78 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: None
LOCALE: None.None
pandas: 0.20.3
pytest: 3.2.2
pip: 9.0.1
setuptools: 28.8.0
Cython: None
numpy: 1.13.3
scipy: None
xarray: None
IPython: None
sphinx: None
patsy: None
dateutil: 2.6.1
pytz: 2017.2
blosc: None
bottleneck: None
tables: None
numexpr: None
feather: None
matplotlib: None
openpyxl: None
xlrd: None
xlwt: None
xlsxwriter: None
lxml: None
bs4: None
html5lib: None
sqlalchemy: None
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
jinja2: None
s3fs: None
pandas_gbq: None
pandas_datareader: None`

Edit 2:

[Full output](https://pastebin.com/b6SwxgG7)

Comment: Give us more information. After running the tests nothing is printed on screen?

Comment: Can you you show the output of `pd.show_version()`?

Comment: @chrisb ```pd.show_version()``` is not a recognized function. The output of ```pd.__version__``` is ```0.20.3```. I'm currently re-running the test and piping the output to a file so I can provide more info.

Comment: Sorry, `pd.show_versions()`  (note the s at the end)

Comment: Output of ```pd.show_versions()``` added to question. @ArthurGouveia I've added a link to pastbin with the full test output.

Answer (score 0):

I think all this should be fixed on master / in the upcoming (~ October 2017) version `0.21.0` release.

The datetime ones are because you are using the newest version of `dateutil`, set of fixes here:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/16880

The warning was a known issue, closed here:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17463

If you try on the development version and any of these still exist, please open an issue on the github repo.
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately building the development version failed so I will wait for the official release of ```0.21.0``` and mark this as the accepted answer then if these errors are resolved.